# Is it a good practice to resort to the send() in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application layout containing a link for logged in users to edit their profile. Initially it was this:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

But then I needed users to be of varying types, I ended up with this:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", send("edit_#{current_user.type.downcase}_path", current_user) %>
```

The "type" column on the Users table is used for STI, where I can magically have subclasses of the User (Model) class, which is super convenient for my purpose.

I also have subclasses of UsersController, so it's a given I will have "edit_**TYPE**_path" paths for every type.

Is there a better way to do this, or am I doing just fine?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the different users to go to different paths? Do you have a different controller for each user type? I might go to the same user path and have the control conditionally show different edit fields.

Comment: Sometimes helpers aren't helping... you can use the actual path... `"/url/for/#{current_user.type.downcase}/#{current_user.id}"`.... I mean, with all due respect for code maintenance, Rails is here to help us, not make things more complicated...

Comment: @yez, I might end up with the users having waaay different controls, so separate controllers seem safer than conditionals (which will add up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [polymorphic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) URL helpers can do the job here:

```
edit_polymorphic_path(current_user)
```

Should do the trick. If you do find yourself needing to use `send`, then (if possible) try to use `public_send` instead. As the name implies this will only call public methods.

As a side note `type.downcase` isn't quite correct - if the class name was FooBar then the route name would be `edit_foo_bar_path` and not `edit_foobar_path`. The `underscore` inflection is closer to what you'd need

Comment: Woah awesome! I knew about neither of those methods. Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The [`polymorphic path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) recommendation is what you need.

You could also use [`eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval) -

```
eval("edit_#{current_user.type.downcase"}_path(#{current_user.id})")
```

... although, obviously, `polymorphic_path` is more preferred.

---

I felt an answer appropriate because of the *structure* of your system (this was picked up in the comments).

The STI stuff is *great* - I don't see it anywhere nearly enough as we should. However, in regards *editing your profile*, I wouldn't think you need to be changing the controller action each time.

Of course, you *may*, and if you do, then I think you know what you're doing.

However, if it were me, I'd keep it all in the `users` controller, even if you had different paths to get there. You can always extrapolate functionality to helpers etc if you need:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:edit, :update], path: "", path_names: {edit: "profile", update: "profile" }
```

This will yield the following urls:

```
# GET   url.com/profile
# PATCH url.com/profile
```

Now....

The important thing here is this sentence:

> edit ***their*** profile

This is a per-user basis.

If you required different functionality, you'd have to use separate controllers, but as you're always going to be guiding the user to *their* profile, I don't believe you'd need anything more than a single controller.

You'd be able to do something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def is? is_type
      type == is_type
   end
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      current_user.is?(:admin) ? change_admin : change_user
   end

   private

   change_admin
      #logic
   end

   change_user
      #logic
   end
end
```

This assumes your users are quite similar in functionality.

Comment: I was considering using a single UsersController, but my user types ended up being quite different in design (beyond updating profiles). There is also a possibility of more user types being added in the future, which seems to be more conveniently done through inheritance rather than conditionals. In any case, it's valuable to know what would someone more experienced have done with the limited background I provided in the question. Thank you for the advice! ^_^

Comment: Okay; if they're that different, are you sure they work with STI's?

Comment: They're actually a peculiar case (at least the existing two subclasses of User) where they have all the same columns and references, with the only difference being in how they can edit the data. It's something of the sort where both a "Server" and a "Client" can have a reference to a sort of "Product" which they have completely different types of control over.

Comment: Oh nice, like admin/user type functionality? We have that too - we use a namespace to separate that stuff out

Comment: Something of the sort. The main reason I wanted to use STI was so the authentication/sessions code would treat users of all types equally without extra concerns. (My SessionsController juggles objects of the User parent type only). I'm curious, how exactly do you use namespaces for that?

Comment: Your eval answer doesn't - look right - you don't want to be interpolation current_user (will end up with a string like #<User ... >

Comment: We implement namespaces for admin functionality, so we'll have the likes of `settings` for Admins, which will allow them to change all sorts of data, including their own profiles. Users (in the front end) can't do this, although both will be using the `User` model